# Updating one-to-many relationships with updateOrCreate methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My main model `Tag` has a one-to-many relationship with `Product` where one `Tag` can have many `Products` assigned to them via `tag_id` relationship on the DB.

On my edit view, I am allowing users to edit the tag `products`. These products can be added/edited/deleted on the form request.

Each `product` field on the form is picked up from a `request()` array. E.g: `request('title'),request('price')`.

I have set `$title[$key]` as the `request('title')` array for example.

My thoughts next, was to loop through each of the `products` for this `tag` and `updateOrCreate` based on the request data. The issue here, is that there's no way of detecting if that particular `product` was indeed needing updated.

**TagController - Update Product Model (One-to-Many)**

```
foreach($tag->products as $key => $product){

  Product::updateOrCreate([
   'id'  => $product->id,
   ],
     [
       'title' => $title[$key],
       'price' => $price[$key],
       'detail' => $detail[$key],
       'order' => $order[$key],
       'tagX' => $tagX[$key],
       'tagY' => $tagY[$key],
       'thumb' => $img[$key],
   ]);
}
```

For the initial `tag` update, I have set an `if` statement which works great (albeit messy) for the main tag `img`.

**TagController - Update Tag Model**

```
//Update the tag collection
if($request->hasFile('img')) {
  $tag->update([
    'name' => $name,
    'hashtag' => $hashtag,
    'img' => $imgPub,
  ]);
} else{
  $tag->update([
    'name' => $name,
    'hashtag' => $hashtag,
  ]);
}
```

Is there a better way to determine if the `product` fields were updated on the request?

Ideally I would like the user to be able to add/remove or edit `products` from the `tag` edit request, but not delete existing product images if they have not been updated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider adding a flag (column) on product entity. So this flag is set once the product is updated and initialized back once you perform the action you want when the product has been updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my view, you are on the wrong track. Tagging relationship should be **Many To Many.**

You must check about `sync()` method of Laravel in ManyToMany relationship. Please check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**Notes:** Please add codes as per your business logic.

**Product.php**

```
  public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Product', 'product_tags', 'tag_id', 'product_id');
  }
```

**Tag.php**

```
   public function tags(){
     return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Tag', 'product_tags', 'product_id', 'tag_id');
  }
```

**ProductController.php**

```
  public function update(Product $products,  Request $request){
    //update the product
    $products->update($request->all());

    //attach new tags to the product 
    $products->tags()->sync($request->input('tag_list'));

    return redirect('articles');
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. There can be multiple `products` assigned to a single `tag` but `products` cannot be assigned to more than one `tag`.

Comment: I have decided to go with `many to many` as suggested by @mayank-dudakiya . I used `detach` then `->sync()` to assign to the pivot table. I will let users update `products` from a separate view to keep things cleaner.

Comment: @scopeak Just to mention eloquent provide a syncWithoutDetach() function, if you only want to attach new products but dont delete existing ones!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I do something similar on the frontend side

```
<div class="product">
   <!-- For Products that may be edited -->
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{$product->id??0}}>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
   <input type="text" name="title" value={{$product->title}}>
      ...
</div>
<div class="product">
   <!-- For New Products -->
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value=0>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
   <input type="text" name="title" value="New Title">
      ...
</div>
<div class="product">
   <!-- For Deleted Products -->
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{$product->id}}>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete">
   <input type="text" name="title" value="New Title">
      ...
</div>
```

Create the json (array of product objects) payload using javascript and send ajax request to the backend

```
[{'id':101,'title':'product 1','action':'update'},
{'id':102,'title':'product 2','action':'update'},
... , 
{'id':201,'action':'delete'}, 
{'id':202, 'action':'delete'},
... ,
{'id':0,'title':'new product 1','action':'add'}, 
{'id':0,'title':'new product 2','action':'add'}]
```

Now on the backend side, loop through the list of products and check for action. Depending on the action, take necessary step.